# Installation of Eclipse failure

Tags: eclipse, installation, configuration

My Error said org.eclipse.artifact-repository code =1003.  Unable to write to repository.  Any body have any thought here?

I downloaded Eclipse using Android Application Development (by Barry Burd) but error upon trying to install.

Comment: Eclipse hasn't been supported for Android development for years now.